# Build a command line from stored value in variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to build a commandline based on a variable VAR1.

If its empty it needs to be set as --arg1 1, else --arg2 $VAR1

This is a simple a script

```
#!/bin/bash -x

export VAR1=1 # Setting this myself for now

if [[ -z $VAR1 ]]
then
    VAR2="--arg1 1"
else
    VAR2="--arg2 \"$VAR1\""
fi

my_command $VAR2
```

When I execute this single quotes are added across $VAR1

```
my_command --arg2 '"1"'
```

I need the output to be

```
my_command --arg2 "1"
```

If you have better approach please do post.

Comment: Why not simply quote `my_command "$VAR2"`?

Comment: Tip: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) would have autodetected [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2089)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin $VAR2 is quoted then